# label top left for textarea when textarea set to a number of columns

Tags: css, label, textarea

I'm sure that this must have been asked before but I cannot find an answer.

I have a div that centers my textareas. This also sets the heading above the textarea in the middle.

I cannot get the heading to be at the top left of the textarea box. I can set the alignment to left and then the heading is in the correct place but they are now both left.

The problem comes in when textarea is set to number of columns. Once this happens, HTML/CSS dosen't seem to know where the top left corner is to place the heading.

Tried almost everything except the right one.

```html
<label for="bikes">Bikes you have owned </label><br/>
<textarea rows='3' cols='50' id='bikes' name='Bikes' >some text </textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: is this what you need https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/w4t0zpsh/1/

Comment: so you want the textarea to be centered on the page and the heading ( bikes you have owned ) to be on the left ? . in your shared code there is no div that wraps the label and textarea and no css either ..

Comment: or try this  https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/w4t0zpsh/2/

Comment: Hi Chandra - First time I used jsfiddle. Cool. Can you center the textarea in the page please. Yours is set to the left. maybe you will see what I mean.

Comment: To clarify, the heading should be over the s in "some text"

Comment: From the lack of replies, looks like this could be a problem. Maybe I'll have to set the textarea using width instead of cols='50'. Then at least the HTML will know where it the top LHS corners is.

Answer (score 0):

Is this What you are looking for?

```css
.txtarea-cont textarea{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="txtarea-cont">
<label for="bikes">Bikes you have owned </label>
       <textarea rows='3' cols='50' id='bikes' name='Bikes' >some text </textarea>
</div>
```